# Why doesn't have the swap memory 'shared', 'buff/cache' and 'available' values?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

As you can see in the picture why is the last three column is empty

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have buff/cache because that's (Block IOs) write/read cache which makes sense to have in RAM because RAM is much faster than a block device but your swap is stored on a block device, not RAM, and then you might as well read or write the data to it's actual location.

Available = free + unneeded cache and since cache doesn't exist at all in swap, available also doesn't.